# Understanding of $|X|=|X_G|+\sum_{i=k}^{n}|O_{x_i}|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the book Abstract Algebra, Theory and Applications by Thomas W. Judson it is written :

[image]

Unfortunately the book don't give any example of $X_G$. I don't understand:

1- How $X_G$ can be? What is an example of it for some $X$ and $G$ and thus $X_G$?

2- What does **non-trivial** orbit means? $O_{x_i}={\{y\in X : gy=x_i for some g\in G}\}$, so $x_i\in O_{x_i}$. Does non-trivial means $O_{x_i}-{\{x_i}\}$?

3- How the sum come up? I mean a rigorous proof for $$|X|=|X_G|+\sum_{i=k}^{n}|O_{x_i}|$$.

Any clear simple explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: Think about why $X_G$ cannot be empty under the action of conjugation for an Abelian group G.

Comment: You missed the "x_k,...,x_n" are representatives from the distinct $\underline{\text{nontrivial}}$ orbits of $X$. The equation is correct since you can divide the sum over all orbits into those for which the orbit is trivial (by definition you have $|X_G|$ such orbits of length $1$) and the non-trivial ones which is the remaining $\sum$ sign.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin - $X_G$ can't be a 'type/category' of orbit since it has the condition **for all g** but in orbit it is **for some g**, am I right?

Comment: @DavidP I think the problem is that I don't understand $X_G$. Would you please tell some example of G and X and so what is $X_G$? The book didn't have any! and I googled but I couldn't find any. Thank you.

Comment: @L.G. If $G=GL(n,K)$ and $X=K^n$ then $G$ acts naturally on $X$, for this action, $X_G$ has only one element : $X_G=\{0\}$. By definition, $X_G$ is the set of elements $x\in X$ that are left fixed by the action of any element $g\in G$ : $g.x=x$. By the definition of the orbit one can actually shows that $x\in X_G$ if and only if $|O_x|=1$ (this is why the $|X_G|$ naturally appears here).

Comment: @L.G. As another example, take $G$ a group and consider its action by conjugation over itself. That is $g.h:=ghg^{-1}$, then you can show that the set $X_G$ is here the center of $G$ noted $Z(G)$ (i.e. the set of elements of $G$ that commute with any element of $G$).

Comment: @ClémentGuérin - thank you for the conjugation example. Would you please help me what will be the nontrivial conjugacy classes of G? I still don't understand 'non-trivial' means here. Does it mean **only** excluding x=id? or more than that 'non-trivial' means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a concrete example from geometry.

Consider the case $X = \big\{ (\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1) \big\}$, the $8$ vertices of a $2\times 2\times 2$ cube centered at origin. 
Let $G$ be the group of $3$-fold rotation (i.e rotation of multiples of $120^\circ$ ) along the diagonal passing through the two vertices $(+1,+1,+1)$ and $(-1,-1,-1)$. These $2$ vertices on the diagonal are invariant under any rotations of $G$. They
are example of $X_G$ i.e.

$$X_G = \big\{ (+1,+1,+1), (-1, -1, -1) \big\}$$

The remaining $6$ vertices falls into two sets.

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{O}_1 &= \big\{ (-1,+1,+1), (+1,-1,+1), (+1,+1,-1) \big\}\\
\text{ and }\quad\mathcal{O}_2 &= 
\big\{ (+1,-1,-1), (-1,+1,-1), (-1,-1,+1) \big\}
\end{align}
$$
Under actions of rotations in $G$, we have:

1. any vertex in $\mathcal{O}_1$ will get rotated to another vertex in $\mathcal{O}_1$, never to one in $\mathcal{O}_2$.
2. any vertex in $\mathcal{O}_2$ will get rotated to another vertex in $\mathcal{O}_2$, never to one in $\mathcal{O}_1$.
3. Given any pair of vertices $x, y$ in the same set, there is always a
   rotation which send $x$ to $y$.

These two sets $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$ are examples of the non-trivial orbits. i.e. orbits that are not singletons and consists of more than one elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually that's a brilliant example with clear explanation, except for I don't know how  by rotation of $120^on$ of (for example) pt (−1,+1,+1) you get pt (+1,−1,+1). I tried by a real cube but still it didn't work for me. How do you calculate them? (I think I need to study Euler rotation matrix in 3d, if there is no other simple way?) thank you.

Comment: @L.G. If you cannot visualize the $3$-fold rotation along the diagonal of a cube. How about the $4$-fold rotation along the $z$-axis for the octahedron with vertices at $(\pm 1,0,0)$, $(0,\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,0,\pm 1)$? In the case of octahedron, $X_G = \{ ( 0, 0, \pm 1 )\}$ while the remaining 4 vertices on the $xy$-plane falls into a single orbit.

Comment: @L.G. By definition, an element $x \in X$ belongs to $X_G$ when any only when $gx = x$ for all $G$, this is equivalent to the set $\{ gx : g \in G \}$ equals to the singleton $\{ x \}$ . This set is nothing but the orbit containing $x$!

Comment: (sorry I deleted my latter comment asking a proof of singleton ... before you sent comment because I thought I found it out, but still don't understand it by your last comment and the other answer also) Would you please help me with one my last question: Intuitively (though not a proof) it makes sense: when $x$ is some element of $X$ such that all the elements of $G$ is used up as action on $x$ but didn't change it to other element of $X$ so the partition of containing $x$ only would contain $x$! (Considering a mathematician's view point) can I consider this intuition as a proof? Thank you.

Comment: @L.G. that's a perfectly valid argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. $X_G$ is the set of elements of $x\in X$ such that $x$ is fixed by the action of any element of $g\in G$. I gave you in comment a relevant case where $X_G$ is non empty : $G$ acts on itself by conjugation. We see, in this example that $x:=1_G$ is fixed by any element $g\in G$ since $g.1_G:=g1_Gg^{-1}=gg^{-1}=1_G$. Hence the definition makes sense and does not always lead to the empty set. As a more trivial example $G$ acting trivially on $X$ then $X=X_G$.
2. Non-trivial  means (in this context) an orbit $O_x$ such that $O_x$ is not reduced to the singleton $x$, i.e. such that you can find $y\in O_x$ with $y\neq x$. Another formulation (in the case of finite sets) is the orbit of $x$ is non-trivial if $|O_x|>1$. Now this is interesting because of the following :

> Take $x\in X$ then we have $x\in X_G\Leftrightarrow |O_x|=1$.

Let us prove this. If $x\in X_G$ then for any $g\in G$, $g.x=x$ so $O_x:=\{g.x|g\in G\}=\{x|g\in G\}=\{x\}$.

On the other hand if $|O_x|=1$ then $O_x=\{x\}$ but if we take any $g\in G$ we will have (by definition of the orbit) $g.x\in O_x$ and since it is contains only $x$, we get $g.x=x$, since it is true for any $g\in G$ we have that $x\in X_G$.

3. If you take $x_1,...,x_r$ representatives of the orbits for the action then clearly :

$$|X|=\sum_{i=1}^r|O_{x_i}| $$

Now you may impose that $x_1...x_{k-1}$ are representative of the trivial orbits and $x_k...x_r$ of the non trivial ones. Hence :

$$|X|=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}|O_{x_i}|+\sum_{i=k}^r|O_{x_i}| $$

Now by definition $|O_{x_i}|=1$ for $i<k$ so :

$$|X|=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}1+\sum_{i=k}^r|O_{x_i}| $$

$$|X|=(k-1)+\sum_{i=k}^r|O_{x_i}| $$

Now by definition $k-1$ is the number of trivial orbits which is by the highlighted result above the number of fixed points of the action ($|X_G|$) so :

$$|X|=|X_G|+\sum_{i=k}^r|O_{x_i}| $$

As for an example take $D_{4}$ the dihedral group of order $8$. Then it has $8$ elements :

$$\{1,r,r^2,r^3,s,sr,sr^2,sr^3\} $$

You have $5$ orbits, representatives are $1$, $r^2$, $r$, $s$, $sr$, among those only $1$ and $r^2$ are trivial. The other being of cardinal $2$.

Hence :

$$|D_4|=|O_1|+|O_{r^2}|+|O_r|+|O_s|+|O_{sr}| $$

$$|D_4|=1+1+2+2+2 $$

Here the two's correspond exactly to the $\sum_{i=k}^r|O_{x_i}|$ whereas the one's correspond to the number of trivial orbits i.e. $|Z(G)|=2$ here.

Comment: I understood all except for the 2. Elements of $O_x$ are those elements of $X$ such that **there exist(s) some** g(s) ... , but elements of $X_G$ are those elements of $X$ such that for **all** g's ... . I can't reconcile two different things: $\exists$ and $\forall$. Thank you.

Comment: If $x\in X_G$ then for all $g$'s, $g.x=x$  (i.e. it is moved by no-one). In this case take $y\in O_x$ then we know that we can find $g_0\in G$ such that $g_0.x=y$. Since $x$ is moved by no-one, in particular it is not moved by $g_0$ so $y=g_0.x=x$. Whence $|O_x|=1$. On the other hand if $|O_x|=1$, take $g\in G$,  by definition there exists $g_0\in G$ such that $g.x=g_0.x$ ($g_0:=g$ is okay) so $g.x\in O_x$, since it only contains $x$ we have $g.x=x$, this being true for all $g\in G$, we have $x\in X_G$ by definition.